# Missing cars in Rocket League

Tags: rocket-league

About 2 years ago, I bought a Rocket League disc that was the legendary edition. The legendary edition came with all the bat mobiles and other stuff. I just noticed that I don't have the bat mobiles anymore. I remember seeing them a couple of months ago before Epic Games bought Rocket League.

I also decided to buy the digital version of the game because it was free, so I didn't have to use my disc. None of my items I had were gone except the bat mobiles.
I don't know if Epic Games took them away or I need the disc to get them back.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already, you probably need to [link your old account and Epic account](https://www.rocketleague.com/activate/).

You can set your preferred/primary platform and share inventory and progress across your accounts.

1. You'll need to sign into (or create) your Epic Games account.
2. Set your primary platform
3. Give it a minute to sync up, restart game if need be.

You should be able to see your old inventory if you synced the correct account(s).

**Note: You now *need* an Epic Games account to play Rocket League**

Comment: Well. I have a epic games account. And I clearly stated, "None of my items I had were gone except the bat mobiles". I have everything but my bat mobiles, I was just wondering if Epic Games or Psyonix had taken them away from my inventory, My account is linked btw.

Comment: Maybe insert the disc, and see if the items appear. I know I had to sign in to each of my platforms to fully sync my inventory and tags. (Primary being PS4 and secondary being Switch)

Comment: I'm not sure why a specific subset of items would be missing otherwise.